# Minimize mis-classification - 0 - 1 output

Tags: regression, self-study, logistic, decision-theory

I am studying logistic regression from the book [Advanced Data Analysis
from an Elementary Point of View](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/ADAfaEPoV.pdf) which states the following on page 280:

> “We minimize the mis-classification rate by predicting whichever class
>   is more likely”:
>
> Let $\hat Y(x)$ be our predicted class, either $0$ or
>   $1$. Our error rate is then $P(Y \neq \hat Y)$ . Show that $P(Y \neq \hat Y)  =   E[(Y −\hat Y)^2]$ .
>
> Further show that $E[(Y− \hat
>  Y)^2|X=x] = Pr(Y=1|X=x)(1−2\hat Y(x))+\hat Y^2(x)$.
>
> Conclude by showing that if $Pr(Y = 1|X = x ) > 0.5$, the risk of
>   mis-classification is mini- mized by taking $\hat Y = 1$, that if
>   $Pr(Y = 1|X = x) < 0.5$ the risk is minimized by taking $\hat Y = 0$,
>   and that when $Pr(Y = 1|X = x) = 0.5$ both predictions are equally
>   risky.

I am a bit lost by this approach, as I have seen the derivations for the Bayes classifier using $L_2$ loss in the continuous case, and using 0-1 loss in the discrete case in [ESL](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) (page 18), but nothing of this sort before.

How should one approach this problem ?

Comment: You should start by expanding out the expectation on the right-hand side of the first equation as an explicit sum over all the possible values of $(Y-\hat{Y})^2$. (Hint: this sum only has two terms in it.)

Comment: isn't that for squared loss ? I am confused by the fact that this seems to be a 0 - 1 output variable, can we apply squared loss in such a case ?

Comment: Indeed that is part of the purpose of this exercise: to show that in the case of a binary target variable, mean squared error is equivalent to the misclassification rate.

Comment: @tddevlin Thanks for your hints it helped a lot, is this correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt following hints by @tddevlin. Since $Y, \hat Y$ can only take values $ \{ 0,1\}$ the algebra is considerably simplified

\begin{aligned}
    E[(Y - \hat Y)^2] &= \sum (Y - \hat Y)^2 Pr((Y-\hat Y)^2)
\\
    & = 1 \times Pr( \ (Y-\hat Y)^2 = 1) + 0 \times Pr( \ (Y-\hat Y)^2 = 0)
\\
& = Pr( \ (Y = 0, \hat Y = 1) \ \cup \ (Y = 1, \hat Y = 0) \ )
\\
& = Pr(Y \neq \hat Y)
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
    E[(Y - \hat Y(x))^2 | X = x] &= E[Y^2 - 2Y \hat Y(x) + \hat Y(x)^2 | X = x]
\\
& = E[Y^2|X=x] - 2\hat Y(x) E[Y|X=x] + \hat Y(x)^2 
\\
& = 1 \times Pr(Y^2 = 1|X=x) -  2\hat Y(x) Pr(Y = 1|X=x) + \hat Y(x)^2 
\\
& = Pr(Y = 1|X=x)[1 -2\hat Y(x)  ] + \hat Y(x)^2 
\end{aligned}

Since $X = x$, the term $\hat Y(x)$ is not a r.v. and $Pr(Y^2 = 1) = Pr(Y = 1)$

Minimizing by equating the derivative w.r.t. $\hat Y(x)$ to zero
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial \hat Y(x)} &= -2 Pr(Y = 1|X=x) + 2 \hat Y(x) = 0
\\
\hat Y(x) &= Pr(Y = 1|X=x)
\end{aligned}

#### Incorrect approach

> Since $\hat Y(x) \in \{0,1\}$ we must round to the nearest value
>   giving
>
> - $ \hat Y(x) = 1$ if $Pr(Y = 1|X=x) > 0.5$
> - $ \hat Y(x) = 0$ if $Pr(Y = 1|X=x) < 0.5$

From comments below: *Implicitly using the claim that if we want to maximize a function $f$ over a discrete set $\{x_1,…,x_n\}$, we need simply choose the $x_i$ which lies closest to the function's maximum $x^∗=\arg \max f(x)$ over its entire domain. This claim **does not** hold*

#### Correct approach

By inspection of the discrete cases. Consider as an example the case where  $Pr(Y = 1|X=x) = 0.7$

The probability of missclassification is $Pr(Y \neq \hat Y | X = x) = 0.7 - 1.4 \hat Y + \hat Y^2$

- If we choose $\hat Y = 0$ then $Pr(Y \neq \hat Y | X = x) = 0.7$
- If we choose $\hat Y = 1$ then $Pr(Y \neq \hat Y | X = x) = 0.3$

Hence in this case we minimize the missclassification error by choosing $\hat Y = 1$. Perform similar calculations for the other case.

Comment: Your answer is correct except for the last part about rounding. You are implicitly using the claim that if we want to maximize a function $f$ over a discrete set $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$, we need simply choose the $x_i$ which lies closest to the function's maximum $x^* = \text{argmax } f(x)$ over its entire domain. This claim does not hold. Again, since the target variable is binary, you can just enumerate the possible cases.

Comment: Excellent ! I have corrected the approach - it is an interesting question and an interesting mistake I made.